# having undefined index error: file

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php script that will upload images into a folder. but it give me an error  Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 26 ,27,28 and 29

```
include('connectdb.php');
if(!file_exists("img")) {
    mkdir ("img");

    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if  (isset($_FILES["file"]["error"]) > 0)
            {

            $er = "ERROR Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />" ;
            }

            else
            {

            $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    //line 26
            $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];    //line 27
            $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];//line 28
            $tmp =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];//line 29
            $path = "img";              

            }                   

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, "img/" . $name)) 
                {
                 $mysql_path = $path."/".$name;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO image(name, path)   VALUES('','$name', '$mysql_path')";

                if (mysql_query($sql)){
                 echo "path inserted in database";
                 }

                 else {

            echo 'path not inserted into database';

                    }

                    }
                }

            ?>
```

and here's the frontend.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Upload </title>
</head>

<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post" name="changer">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML form you have `name="image"` but in PHP script you work with `$_FILES["file"]`. It should be `$_FILES["image"]`.